# What Android packages are available for vector, scalar, matrix, and FP math?

Tags: android, math

What packages are suggested to perform complex math operations like vector multiplication, vector conversions(int to FP), etc. on the Android platform.  It does not look like java.lang.math is stout enough.  It has been suggested I look into the NDK and a good c/c++ lib or siglib.  Are there any other suggestions? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Last year, I was reading [a book](http://www.gameenginebook.com/) that included a topic on SIMD math. As you probably know, SIMD math is used for accelerating vector multiplication and vector conversion processes, I looked into Sony's VectorMath library.

It was convenient and easy to use, even though I had no intent to build processor expensive applications. I think a problem would be that it was actually designed for Sony PS3 processor architecture and I am not sure if it is available on ARM chipsets.

Here are links: 
Bullet SIMDMath library: http://bullet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bullet/trunk/Extras/simdmathlibrary/

Bullet VectorMath Library: http://bullet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bullet/trunk/Extras/vectormathlibrary/

**EDIT**

Directly quoting from wikipedia ARM Architecture page:

> Advanced SIMD (NEON)
>   The Advanced SIMD extension (aka NEON or "MPE" Media Processing Engine) is a combined 64- and 128-bit single instruction multiple data (SIMD) instruction set that provides standardised acceleration for media and signal processing applications. NEON is included in all Cortex-A8 devices but is optional in Cortex-A9 devices.[33] NEON can execute MP3 audio decoding on CPUs running at 10 MHz and can run the GSM adaptive multi-rate (AMR) speech codec at no more than 13 MHz. It features a comprehensive instruction set, separate register files and independent execution hardware.[34] NEON supports 8-, 16-, 32- and 64-bit integer and single-precision (32-bit) floating-point data and operates in SIMD operations for handling audio and video processing as well as graphics and gaming processing. In NEON, the SIMD supports up to 16 operations at the same time. The NEON hardware shares the same floating-point registers as used in VFP. Devices such as the ARM Cortex-A8 and Cortex-A9 support 128-bit vectors but will execute with just 64 bits at a time,[32] whereas newer Cortex-A15 devices can execute 128 bits at once.

That means even though there is no warranty for SIMD instructions, they are likely to have.

And Tegra Family:

> Compared to Tegra 2, the ARM Cortex-A9s in Tegra 3 now supports ARM's SIMD extension—NEON.

Comment: Thanks again Mehmet for your answer - It takes time to give such complete and thorough comments and I appreciate your service.